# How to find which Method methods are invoked from and variables are declared within

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to map variables declared and methods invoked to where they are declared/invoked from. I'm developing a stand-alone application.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  static ArrayList methodsDeclared = new ArrayList();
  static ArrayList methodsInvoked = new ArrayList();
  static ArrayList variablesDeclared = new ArrayList();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  ...

  public static void parse(String file) {
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(file.toCharArray());
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

      public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
        methodsDeclared.add(node);
        return false;
      }

      public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
        methodsInvoked.add(node);
        return false;
      }

      public Boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
        variablesDeclared.add(node);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

By the end, I have 3 ArrayLists with the information I need. the methods in the file, the variable declared and the methods invoked. I want to be able to find specifically which variables are defined in which methods (if not class variables) and which methods are invoked from which methods. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need the space where you store the information that the variable "X" is located inside method "Y". You need to change the type of `methodsDeclared` from `ArrayList` (which should contain generics anyway) to `Map<MethodDeclaration, Set<VariableDeclarationFragment>>`.

```
static final Map<MethodDeclaration, Set<VariableDeclarationFragment>> methodDeclared = new HashMap<MethodDeclaration, Set<VariableDeclarationFragment>>();
```

In your visitor method for the `MethodDeclaration` type you add/create a new entry in this field.

```
HelloWorld.methodDeclared.put(node, new HashSet<VariableDeclarationFragment>());
```

In your visitor method for the `VariableDeclarationFragment` type you add the variable declaration to the method declaration this variable declaration is in. You need the `getParent()` method to look for the method declaration. Then use this information to access the right entry in the Map and add the variable declaration to the set.

```
// find the method declaration from the "node" variable
MethodDeclaration methodOfVariable = FindMethodDeclaration(node); // node is of type "VariableDeclarationFragment"
// add the node to the method declaration
HelloWorld.methodDeclared.get(methodOfVariable).add(node);
```

> *Note: You have to write such a `FindMethodDeclaration` or check the API if there is such a helper method.*

After you have run the code, the field `methodDeclared` will contain every method declaration in the keys and the values will contain the variable declarations.

Comment: The information has been fairly helpful, however, the key aspect that drove me to ask this question is because I cannot find a way to match the getParent of a VariableDeclarationFragment to a methodDeclaration. You suggested finding a method in the API called FindMethodDeclaration, however, in my experience, none exist. I could convert them into Strings and use stull like String.compareTo, however, I think this is rather messy and wanted to see if the community has any better solutions?

Comment: @Jimmy The `FindMethodDeclaration()` method would be just a while loop combined with getParent() calls. You go to the parent node up until you hit the method declaration. Something like `while (currentNode != null) { if (currentNode is a MethodDeclaration) { \o/ } else { currentNode = currentNode.getParent(); }}`. Converting the nodes to String and compare the strings is not advisable. You have the parsed tree with all the informations (name, children, parent, type, content, hobbies, friends, jobs, ...) available, so use them.